# Trying to access ACF value in functions.php, in woocommerce_email_order_details action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a Wordpress installation with Woocommerce and I added a ACF field to the orders. It's called 'booking_reference'.

Inside my functions.php file, on checkout I update the 'booking_reference' custom field. It gets saved to the database. All is working as it should.

In my next function i'm trying to email this custom field to the customer. I use this code:

```
$order_id   = $order->get_id();
$reference_number_acf_order = get_field('booking_reference', $order_id );
```

When I echo $reference_number_acf_order, it's empty. The $order_id variable is correct. It contains the order correct order ID.

The rest of the email to the customer is correct, it contains data from the order. Only the ACF value is empty.

Comment: If possible, share the process code you are doing to get more information about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are u using `WP_Query()` or something like in your new function?

If so. try calling `wp_reset_query();` first:

```
wp_reset_query();
$reference_number_acf_order = get_field('booking_reference', $order_id );
```

Comment: I'm not using WP_Query() but I am using $wpdb().

Comment: Another strange thing is this, if I manually set the ID for the order, on the first order I make the reference code is empty. If I order another product, the reference code is coming in the confirmation email.

Comment: If you are have access to your MySQL DB then I suggest you fetching your ref number directly via `$reference_number_acf_order = $wpdb->query("YOUR_SQL_QUERY_HERE")`, the only problem is AFC field's location in the DB varies by the AFC plugin version :)

Comment: :D cant u just simply login to the phpmyadmin and look into that table cell why the hell is it empty? :D Or maybe your SQL query is incorrect. I usually try my queries in phpmyadmin before touching the template

Comment: I added code to email the reference code on status change. So if a booking is confirmed from admin, manually, the reference code get added to the email.

Comment: I've also added a function to set all new bookings to status "confirmed" automatically. The email comes with reference code empty in this case. I'm sharing my code on pastebin now. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: here is my code: [link](https://pastebin.com/MKSvvBz1) . I'm only testing for the first case, where `$product_id == 3763`

Comment: What happens if you put `die($reference_number_acf . ' >>> ' . $reference_number_acf_order);` on line 93 ? Is it gonna print out correct values?

Comment: Well, if `booking_reference` is assigned correctly to both order and its booking, then maybe the problem lies in the hook `woocommerce_order_status_processing` - is function `set_bookings_confirmed` firing in the right moment? If not, try using another hook - something like `add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'set_bookings_confirmed', 20 );` instead